# Banner ad dont show Admob

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

Hello and thanks to try to help me, im trying to implement some ads in my app with admob in android studio, i followed all the tutorials, but when i try to load my app no ad is shown, im trying with the banner example ad ("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111").

Here is my code:

**Adroid Manifest**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2069240735008902~XXXXXXX(Here is my admob id)">
</meta-data>
```

**Build.gradle app**

```
ependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha06"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
...
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        MobileAds.initialize(this){}
        var mAdView:AdView = findViewById(R.id.anuncio1)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
        }
}
```

**Activity_main.xlm**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/anuncio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks you all for the help, i will be very glad.

Comment: Are there any errors on the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks exactly how it should be.

What I guess: you need to have an internet connection, even for the test ad. Otherwise, nothing is shown.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, you were rigth, in the android studio emulator i dont have wifi